# postgres: (sub)select and combine optional content into an array

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have the following table structure:

Location----- * Media ----1 Attribute --------* AttributeTranslation

Each Location has n mediaitems attached, containing one optional attribute (text) and n associated translationa for that attribute.

I need to select this data into an array, so that i get for each location the associated medialist for each language.

what i currently do and what i get:

```
 SELECT m.location_id, t.language_id,
        array_agg_mult(
          ARRAY[ARRAY[m.sortorder::text, m.filename, t.name]] ORDER BY m.sortorder
        ) as medialist 

 FROM Media m

 LEFT JOIN ATTRIBUTE a ON a.id = m.attribute_id
 LEFT JOIN AttributeTranslation t ON a.id = t.attribute_id

 WHERE m.location_id = ?
 GROUP BY m.location_id, t.language_id
```

This gives me following result for the given scenario: the current location has 4 images attached, only the first image has an associated attribute containing two translations:

```
Location_ID    Language_ID      MEDIALIST
  AT_014           1            {{1,'location_image1.jpg','attribute german'}}
  AT_014           2            {{1,'location_image1.jpg','attribute english'}}
  AT_014                        {{2,'location_image2.jpg',null},{3,'location_image3.jpg',null},{4,'location_image4.jpg',null}}
```

but what i need instead is this:

```
Location_ID    Language_ID      MEDIALIST
  AT_014           1            {{1,'location_image1.jpg','attribute german'},{2,'location_image2.jpg',null},{3,'location_image3.jpg',null},{4,'location_image4.jpg',null}}
  AT_014           2            {{1,'location_image1.jpg','attribute english'},{2,'location_image2.jpg',null},{3,'location_image3.jpg',null},{4,'location_image4.jpg',null}}
```

those 3 columns are part of a view, so that i can do later:

```
select * from locationview where location_id = ? and language_id = ?
```

how can i achieve the desired result here? thanks in advance!

Simplified Table  Definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE LOCATION (  
  location_id numeric(20) primary key,              
  description text
);

CREATE TABLE MEDIA (  
  media_id numeric(20) primary key,             
  fileName text,
  sortorder smallint,   
  location_id numeric(20) references LOCATION(location_id), 
  attribute_id numeric(20) references ATTRIBUTE(attribute_id)
);

CREATE TABLE ATTRIBUTE (  
  attribute_id numeric(20) primary key,             
  attributetype varchar(100),
);

CREATE TABLE ATTRIBUTETRANSLATION (  
  translation_id numeric(20),               
  language_id smallint,
  name text,
  description text,
  attribute_id numeric(20) references ATTRIBUTE(attribute_id)
);

ALTER TABLE ATTRIBUTETRANSLATION add constraint AT_ID primary key(translation_id, language_id)
```

Comment: Please provide the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables involved.

Comment: i've updated the question with the table definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand your question, but here's an attempt. You could take the output of your query, and match each row that has a `language_id` with the corresponding rows where `language_id` is `NULL`, so that you can then concatenate the `medialist` arrays. Here's a way to do that by creating an alias of your query with a CTE:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT m.location_id, t.language_id,
           array_agg(
             ARRAY[ARRAY[m.sortorder::text, m.filename, t.name]] ORDER BY m.sortorder
           ) as medialist 

    FROM Media m

    LEFT JOIN ATTRIBUTE a ON a.attribute_id = m.attribute_id
    LEFT JOIN AttributeTranslation t ON a.attribute_id = t.attribute_id

    WHERE m.location_id = ?
    GROUP BY m.location_id, t.language_id
)
SELECT location_id, t1.language_id, t1.medialist || t2.medialist AS medialist
FROM (SELECT * FROM t WHERE language_id IS NOT NULL) t1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM t WHERE language_id IS NULL) t2 USING (location_id);
```

I am not sure if this does exactly what you want, but hopefully it will give you some ideas.

Comment: thanks. you fully understand the question and this is leading into the right direction :) the problem that remains, that the query returns no rows for media that have no attributes/translations. in that case i would need the result of the CTE. but i'll keep trying it out..

Comment: Maybe replacing my `JOIN` with a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` would help then?

Comment: sadly not because column language_id is null then and the current WHERE clause at the end (t1.language_id IS NOT NULL AND t2.language_id IS NULL) does not match any more. thought, this would be easiser... -.-

Comment: Well, in that case, let's move these conditions inside a subquery in `FROM`. Check my updated answer.

Comment: oh dear, 2 days of headache are over now. that's it. i try to understand your solution now. thank you so much!